# trying to rewrite each - is there a better approach to this?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to create my own each similar to jquery each. I get the expected output. I'm not sure why supplying "this" to the callback.call makes my code work. Is there any other approach to achieve the same behavior?

```
function print(val){
  console.log(val);
}

function each(list, callback){
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    callback.call(this, list[i]);  
  }
}


var list = [1, 2, 3];

each(list, print);
```

Comment: You can just use `list.forEach(print)`

Comment: there is no need to pass `this`

Comment: Removing "this" gives me undefined.

Comment: Did you have `callback.call(list[i]);` instead of `callback(list[i]);`?

Comment: thats right! :) However if I want to keep my each as it is. Could I modify my print function to print it without the "this" within each function? I'm really trying to get "this".

Comment: `function print(){  console.log(this);}`

Comment: ^^ this is the answer :)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `call`?

Comment: This *each* is nothing like jQuery's *each*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation of what you did. Using the `call` function, the first parameter is to define the "this" of the function called. Which means, that if I do `myFunction.call(1, 2, 3);`, within `myFunction` `this == 1, param1 == 2, param2 == 3`.

Calling the function using a "normal" call `myFunction(1)` doesn't set the this. So this time `param1 == 1`.